# useState keeps initial state after defining it in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I have an async function that fetches some data from an API. Since I need that data to properly load my component I decided to fetch the data in the useEffect and then store it in a useState what works just fine. However, if I try to console log it, it just shows its initial state what technically would mean it's still unset or that the console log runs before assigning the useState.

Thanks for your help in advance.

```
const [categories, setCategories] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    fetchListProductCats().then(function(result){
        setCategories(result.data)
    })
    console.log(categories) // returns -> []
    
}, []);

if(!categories.length){
    return "loading"
}
```

Comment: You said it yourself, it's async, the data hasn't been set at the time you are logging it.

Comment: Yes that's what I thought, but how do I wait for the async function to finish?

Comment: Well in this case, not only is your function async, but setting state in React is also async. So you will need to use another effect to wait for changes to `categories`  (As described in a couple of the answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async` function with Promise, make sure you know what it means.

The `console.log` line in this code always runs before the Promise resolved.

If you want to observe the changing of categories, use another `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(categories);
}, [categories]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I do it like you suggested the console.log runs twice, the first time it runs it logs an empty array like it did before and the second time it logs the filled Array. I am not sure since I am quite new to React. isn't it bad performance-wise? I mean if it's one function it probably won't have a noticeable effect however if my project is on a larger scale it will surely cause a delay?

Comment: @Luke_KS There is an [official document](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) explains this. Actually the second parameter determines the running performance of this hook. Generally, only several comparisons of the value in the array will occur each time it rerender. It's safe and further further less than the performance consumed by other steps when rerendering.

Answer (score 1):

Your state is already updated with data you wanted its showing categories with it's initial values because you have rendered useEffect with no dependancies.
And it is consoled befored being updated.
Try using below code snippets to log.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(categories)
}, [categories]);
```

Answer (score 1):

React `setState` is async. It won't update immediately after calling the function. It will go through a re-rendering process first to update the user interface. Once re-rendering is done, the functions provided in the `useEffect` hook will be called.

```
useEffect(()=>{
  console.log(categories)
}, [categories])
```